# TV series where space captain dies leaving children in charge of ship

Tags: story-identification, movie

Need help with the name of a TV series I believe is from the 80's. A group of kids from about 5 to their early 20's set out for another planet that's light years away. The captain is in his 30-40's. The captain gets killed when an airlock blows him into space. The boy that was suppose to take over reluctantly does. Later in the show they meet this guy on an abandoned station and rescue him. He turns out to be a pain in the butt.

Does anyone remember the name of the show/mini series.

Comment: I'll bet a shiny penny that you can remember more. Were the characters caucasian or black? Was the show in black and white or colour? What were the character's names? Was the show in English? Why did the airlock blow him into space? Was this animated or live-action?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silversun?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager?

Comment: Earth Star Voyager seems almost certain.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly *[Earth Star Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Star_Voyager)*. It has the crew with children:

> Command cadet Jonathan Hays, twenty-one, and his best friend Jessie 'Beanie' Bienstock, a 14-year-old computer specialist, are among the young military cadets chosen to serve as the crew of Earth*Star Voyager, the planet's newest interstellar vessel.

The captain is blown out of an airlock and a witnessing child accepts the responsibility for taking over:

> While checking the repairs on an airlock, Captain Forbes finds himself trapped inside with the system set to open the airlock to space. Moments later, coming to check on the Captain, Jonathan finds him before the airlock opens. Before being blown into space, the Captain tells Jonathan to keep going and to 'complete the mission'.

And they pick up **two** guys from space stations although the one from an abandoned one turns out to be very helpful. It's the second guy that's a pain.

> Along the way to Demeter, they pick up the long lost astronaut Capt. Jacob 'Jake' Brown, while stopping at an abandoned station to make some repairs. Brown initially paralyzes Huxley with a weapon but it is revealed that he did so to prevent Huxley from walking straight into an "anti-matter zone."

...

> The next discovery, explaining how Vance and Willie got to the World's Fair Station in the first place was finding the wreckage of the Vanguard Explorer ... [and] ... an unwelcome guest known as a 'Shell'—a cyborg. Brown is able to shock the Shell into unconsciousness, and Doctor Arthur insists they take him to the ship to help and examine him...
>
> ... After making some small adjustments to him to ease his discomfort, Doctor Arthur and he form a brief emotional connection before his programming returns him to his drone-state. Later he regains his full movement and smashes his way through the ship, damaging Capt. Brown's jury-rigged railgun weapon and one of Priscilla's processors. The Shell warns them that they must stop "Assembly" then deactivates himself rather than let his programming make him kill Dr. Arthur.

You can generally find copies of it on Youtube. It was a miniseries never released on DVD although there was at least one VHS copy.

Comment: Also shows up at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56652/movie-with-a-space-ship-full-of-kids?rq=1, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/what-is-this-disney-scifi-movie-from-the-late-80s-early-90s, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47585/what-film-has-a-space-ship-crewed-by-very-young-people-journeying-to-a-distant-p?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33385/movie-from-the-70s-or-80s-that-had-a-cyborg?noredirect=1&lq=1, and others. It's popular. :)

Comment: You guys are awesome!! For some reason I just couldn't remember but a few details about it. Probably because I saw it as a kid. I remembered I loved it. Thank you!!

Comment: @Ash: You can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.